# How to call a javascript anonymous object without knowing the name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading some javascript modules dynamically using jquerys getScript.  I'd like to be able to then call an init method that all of the modules have.  The modules are loaded dynamically so I'd prefer not to hard code the names.  Is it possible to somehow call the init without using a constructor?

```
 $.getScript("/mydynamicmodule.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

              myModuleName.init()         

            });
```

Comment: What do you modules look like? And what function to you have to 'init' the modules?

Comment: If you don't know the module, you must provide an api for the module to register itself (e.g. handing you over its `init` function)

Comment: can't you just call the init method in the code of your module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of what Samer suggested, you already have a string for the module location, e.g., "/mydynamicmoudle.js".  I don't know how you are getting this string (i.e., are you loading it from somewhere, etc), but you can try something along the lines of:

```
function openModule(name) {
    $.getScript("/"+name+".js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        window[name].init();
    }
}
```

This assumes your module has an alias that can be derived from your file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your module names in the global namespace (`window`), then you could try this:

```
window['myModule'].init();
```

Comment: "without knowing the name"